# why is Date not localized correctly in a Wicket TitleAttributeBehavior?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, wicket

I'm adding a popup to a wicket `DateLabel` using `TitleAttributeBehavior` and a `StringResourceModel`.  The application needs to be localized, and it's partly working but not 100%.

```
item.add(new DateLabel(componentId, new Model<Date>(sub.getExpiryDate()), new StyleDateConverter(false))   //adds the label with the date
  .add(new TitleAttributeBehavior(new StringResourceModel("sub.next.payment.popup", CCBasePage.this, new Model<CCSubscription>(sub)))));
```

The label itself is formatted correctly for the locale (German).  However the Date in the popup test is not.

The StringResourceModel is quite clever and calls both `getCCNextPaymentAmount()` and `getExpiryDate()` on the `CCSubscription` object `sub`.

properties file:

```
sub.next.payment.popup=Nachste Zahlung ${cCNextPaymentAmount} wird am ${expiryDate} genommen
```

where CCSubscription.getExpiryDate() returns Date - unformatted.  Also note that CCBasePage.getLocale() returns "de_DE" - ie the component and session have the correct locale set.

so I would expect wicket to correctly format the Date in the popup text.

How can I get wicket to format the date in the popup correctly?  I'm using wicket 1.4.22.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried specifying a `SimpleDateFormat` pattern in the resource String? For instance `sub.next.payment.popup="Nachste Zahlung ${cCNextPaymentAmount} wird am ${expiryDate,date, EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy} genommen`. I guess what's happening behind the scenes is a `toString()`, that's why it's appearing in English.
"The date is: {0, date, }"

Comment: Hi, I tried that but got: `org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No get method defined for class: class mycompany.er.cc.bl.CCSubscription expression: expiryDate,date, EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Comment: This was improved with WICKET-3753 in 1.5.8.